# Successfully firing two useReducer hooks in a row

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a useReducer hook

```
const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);
```

It has two cases that set a string on state

```
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ONE':
      return { a: action.payload };
    case 'TWO':
      return { b: action.payload };

    default:
      throw new Error('You have probably mispelt the action name');
  }
}
```

If I call dispatch twice in a row then only the last call registers, just like it would with component set state.

```
dispatch({ type: 'ONE', payload: 'some string' });
dispatch({ type: 'TWO', payload: 'some other string' });
```

How do I get both dispatch calls to register, not just the last one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are overriding the state.

Instead of doing `return { a: action.payload };` , use :

```
return { ...state, a: action.payload };
```

Same thing for the other case